# Is convenient to show a menu at this way?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, menu

I'm creating a menu, but I think showing a window in each menu it's so annoying. So I think showing an user control to a certain grid row is a good way. Look at this:

I've got a menu: Students and Groups. Then I select one of them, and it shows below a command list. If you click one of these commands, it'll show an UserControl.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
    private void AddStudentButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddStudentUserControl userControl = new AddStudentUserControl();
        grid.Children.Add(userControl);

        Grid.SetRow(userControl, 2);
    }
```

Although, at the same time, I'd have to create many buttons with event command. What do you think? Is a good way to present the data? If so, will you do me an example about how will you do this? I want to do different things or improve my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an unusual UI paradigm that would confuse most users. UX design is as more about respecting decades of experience using conventional UIs than it is about interesting ideas. If you want to depart from convention, that's fine (innovation is a wonderful thing), but it had better be for something vastly better than the status quo.

In this case, you could just use a tabbed interface to present students and groups as lists, with UI elements to add and remove elements bundled into each view (often a `[+]` somewhere in the header and an `[x]` next to each item, combined with mappings for the <kbd>Ins</kbd> and <kbd>Del</kbd> keys).

Comment: If much trouble to show me an example the last line? I don't get it

Comment: @oscar.fimbres: See [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/alleditablecolumns/defaultcs.aspx) for a demo of a rich grid control illustrating the use of `[+]` and `[x]` buttons. When you click `[+]`, it integrates a "New Product" form into the grid.

Comment: Guau, I really like that idea, the UI is simplier. But it would be difficult to programming in WPF?

Comment: I don't know WPF. But this isn't rocket-science. I'll be astounded if there isn't something out of the box that does what you need.

Comment: +1 for UX, tab control, and list/grid view suggestion.  Though the `Ins` and `Del` keys - not sure if those match UX standards or not under Windows.  @oscar.fimbres: There are plenty of ListView and GridView tutorials that could tell you *how* to do what Marcelo is suggesting.

Comment: I'm watching at this tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/WPFDataGridLINQtoSQL10292009010513AM/WPFDataGridLINQtoSQL.aspx

I want to imitate the way when you add a new registry. Because I don't like the idea to add the new registry in the last row.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a UI like this.. look at the `Ribbon`.

Comment: Yes, if "a UI like this" is interpreted as "non-standard, difficult to use, and not recommended for typical applications".

Comment: Well the op asked if such a Ui existed... im not commenting on the advisability of using or nor using it

Comment: I agree with pickles, it looks like ribbon control is what oscar is talking about and I don't think its "non-standard, difficult to use, and not recommended for typical applications" by any means.